# Php form fails to commit information to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I inherited this messy code from the student in my job before me. I believe it can be written in a more efficient and easier way but I'm not sure how to go about cleaning it up. My hope is that by writing it in a better way I might find the error that's preventing the form data from being submitted.

```
$statement = db::getInstance()->prepare('INSERT INTO `Training_Log` (
`Trainees_Name`,
`Date`,
`Time`,
`Bus_Number`,
`Trainer`,
`Training_Shift_Number`,
`Number_of_Hours`,
`Total_Number_of_Hours`,
`Static_Comments`,
`PreTrip_Comments`,
`Road_Driving_Comments`,
`RailRoad_Comments`,
`Bus_Stop_Comments`,
`Route_Comments`, )
     VALUES(NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $statement->bind_param('sssiiiissssss', $_SERVER['HTTP_CAS_USER'],    
    $_POST['sec1_trainee'], $_POST['sec1_trainer'], $_POST['sec1_datetime'], 
    $_POST['sec1_bus'], $_POST['sec1_shiftnum'], $_POST['sec1_numhour'], 
    $_POST['sec1_totnumhour'], $_POST['static'], $_POST['pretrip'], 
    $_POST['roaddriving'], $_POST['railroad'], $_POST['busstop'], $_POST['routes']);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a PHP based tool for interacting with your MySQL database. It is not your database.

Comment: What error is showing? Can you add your error in question?

Comment: thats the problem, there is no error generated. It says I submitted my form successfully however when I go to the db table, my entry is not there

Comment: `Trainees_Name` is being given `NOW()` so the subsequent `Date` field is being given an incorrectly formatted value from `?` which is binded with the value `sssiiiissssss`

Comment: you have field mismatch problem.Date is not now() value

Comment: what kind of value should date be given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the trailing comma in your insert columns list.

```
`Route_Comments`, )
```

Should be

```
`Route_Comments`)
```

(There are probably other issues too. Like the fact that you're inserting a DATE into a field called *_name?)

You don't see any errors because you're not checking for any errors.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php